# dnf update failed - pushed back to login-screen after update

Tags: fedora, dnf, software-updates

I installed a fresh copy of Fedora 24 on my older notebook (1.gen i5) a few weeks ago and (naturally) first tried to get the latest updates through `dnf` (`sudo` will be omitted here).

After a while (still running `dnf`) I got pushed back to the login-screen and when I logged in, all terminal-windows were gone. After a restart I noticed that the kernel hasn't been updated (though I saw a newer version had been queued and my VMs also use a newer one).

Another run of `dnf update` says that there are no packages available for updating. Refreshed the cash with `dnf clean all` but that did not help.
So I tried to undo the last update by running `dnf history undo <id>` but I then get the message:

> No package  available. Error: An operation cannot be
>   undone

The package-name varies every time I run the command.

I had that issue right after a fresh installation and so I reinstalled a few times and later used an online-installer which I booted from CD instead of USB. This worked fine and I was able to update without any error. So I thought that it was just a problem with the way I installed it (YUMI created the USB-device and I think that is not really supported).
But now a few weeks later, I got the same issue.

The system hasn't been modified in any way, honestly, I haven't even used it for a while.
The currently installed kernel is 4.6.4-301 and it tried to install 4.6.6.

Any ideas how to fix that or what I can check?

**UPDATE:**
After reinstalling the system with a netinstall-image so that I start with the newest updates, it ran fine for some time.
But now I got the same issues again (this time no kernel update, but same issue).

I noticed that I have some duplications by checking `rpm -qa`.
Especially systemd hasn't been updated correctly so that I have two versions of it.
I tried to reinstall it with

```
sudo dnf reinstall systemd -y --allowerasing --best
```

but that did not work (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know why exactly that happened (the Fedora-QA guys are currently figuring that out), I got the answer to repair it (thanks go to Fedora-QA guys again).

1. Check for duplicated packages by running
   `rpm -qa`

   It will look like:

   systemd-229-13.fc24.x86_64
   systemd-229-15.fc24.x86_64
   ...

   Best way to do this (as you may have a lot of packages) is to check for
   all packages that have been touched by the update. To see that check
   `sudo dnf history info`
    It will return the packages touched by the last update.
    Now run `rpm -qa | grep *package-name*` to get just all packages with 
    that name.
2. Remove the old packages
   `rpm -e *package-name* --justdb --nodeps`
3. Reinstall the new package
   `sudo dnf reinstall *package-name*`